# How do I open a Tab delimited Text file in Excel using Perl and OLE?

Tags: excel, perl, text, ole

Originally I tried to open a XML file with Excel. But as this takes ages I parsed the XML myself into a Tab delimited text file. I thought I found the correct syntax in the internet. I tried below code using the values I recorded with an Excel Macro. I have an 18 column Tab delimited file. The error occures in the last line of below code when calling "Worksheets" Method.

**Error message:**
*Can't call method "Worksheets" without a package or object reference at ./PostProcessingDev.pl line 70.*

```
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
Win32::OLE->Option(Warn => 3);

use strict;

my $Excel;
my $Sheet;
my $Workbook;


$Excel = CreateObject OLE "Excel.Application";

$Workbook =  $Excel->Workbooks->OpenText({Filename =>"$inSelf->{'TXT'}",
  Origin => xlMSDOS,
  StartRow => 1,
  DataType => xlDelimited, 
  TextQualifier => xlDoubleQuote, 
  ConsecutiveDelimiter => "False", 
  Tab => "True",
  Semicolon => "False",
  Comma => "False",
  Space => "False",
  Other => "False",
  FieldInfo => [[1, xlTextFormat],
    [2, xlTextFormat],
    [3, xlTextFormat],
    [4, xlTextFormat],
    [5, xlTextFormat],
    [6, xlTextFormat],
    [7, xlTextFormat],
    [8, xlTextFormat],
    [9, xlTextFormat],
    [10, xlTextFormat],
    [11, xlTextFormat],
    [12, xlTextFormat],
    [13, xlTextFormat],
    [14, xlTextFormat],
    [15, xlTextFormat],
    [16, xlTextFormat],
    [17, xlTextFormat],
    [18, xlTextFormat]],
  TrailingMinusNumbers => "True"});

$Sheet = $Workbook->Worksheets(1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really have to parse TSV using Excel? If there is nothing fancy in your files, you might well use something like this:

```
my $file = 'some tsv file';
{
    open my $in,"<",$file  or die "$file: $!";
    while(<$in>) {
        chomp;
        my @cols = split /\t/;
        # do something with columns in @cols array
    }
}
```

If Excel is needed for a reason I cannot see, the problem is that `OpenText` method returns True/False and not `Workbook` object. This works:

```
use strict;

use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
use Data::Dump;     # for dd

Win32::OLE->Option(Warn => 3);

my $Excel = Win32::OLE->new("Excel.Application");
$Excel->Workbooks->OpenText({
    Filename             => 'enter the full path to file',
    Origin               => xlMSDOS,
    StartRow             => 1,
    DataType             => xlDelimited,
    TextQualifier        => xlDoubleQuote,
    Tab                  => "True",
    TrailingMinusNumbers => "True"
});

my $Sheet = $Excel->ActiveWorkbook->Worksheets(1);
my $Data = $Sheet->UsedRange()->{Value};

dd $Data;    # arrayref (rows) of arrayrefs (columns)
```

Comment: You should not parse xSV files by splits/regexes. Same as CSV, use a proper module (Text:CSV_CS)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. No I don't use Excel as parser. The parsing part I wrote myself as I can neither use or install the required mudules. I'm doing everything inside Pearl arrays. The TSV as well as the Excel file is the output. As writting Excel Cell by Cell is to slow (tenthousands of lines) compared to opening a TSV I just want to open the TSV and store it as Excel. Trying your code on a 4 line text file, it stucks inside the OpenText method. How can I see what happens? Can I debug OLE methods?

Comment: I did not understand properly what you want. If you write out CSV with .CSV extension, Excel is associated and is able to open it directly. Per `OLE` debugging, it is a bit tricky, but you can put `$Excel->{Visible} = 1;` after initialization and you can see what is going in Excel.

Comment: @DVK If you know what your data is, why not split? TSV has advantage of tab character being rare in database-like data. Naturally it should not go into production to process arbitrary data.

Comment: @bvr - Trust me, the first time your script fails because the data contained wanky stuff (which it will) you will start wishing you didn't reinvent the bicycle (poorly)

Comment: @DVK Too late - many of my scripts have failed in the face of user creativity, either using parser or hand-rolled solutions. But I am taking your point - the parser is certainly way to go, at least it is much better tested than my code will ever be.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for at all for your answers. This resolved my issue. All I wanted to do with the OpenText method was to convert a TSV file to Excel as this is the result format I require. As I couldn't find a solution on the web before I like to provide the complete code:

```
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
use strict;

Win32::OLE->Option(Warn => 3);

my $FileName = "Complete Path of TSV File";

my $Excel = Win32::OLE->new("Excel.Application");

# Open Tab separated Text file in Excel, all 18 columns are "Text" formated
$Excel->Workbooks->OpenText({
  Filename      => $FileName,
  Origin        => xlMSDOS,
  StartRow      => 1,
  DataType      => xlDelimited,
  TextQualifier => xlDoubleQuote,
  Tab           => "True",
  FieldInfo     => [[1, xlTextFormat],
    [2, xlTextFormat],
    [3, xlTextFormat],
    [4, xlTextFormat],
    [5, xlTextFormat],
    [6, xlTextFormat],
    [7, xlTextFormat],
    [8, xlTextFormat],
    [9, xlTextFormat],
    [10, xlTextFormat],
    [11, xlTextFormat],
    [12, xlTextFormat],
    [13, xlTextFormat],
    [14, xlTextFormat],
    [15, xlTextFormat],
    [16, xlTextFormat],
    [17, xlTextFormat],
    [18, xlTextFormat]],
  TrailingMinusNumbers => "True"
});

my $Sheet = $Excel->ActiveWorkbook->Worksheets(1);
$Sheet->Activate;

my $Workbook = $Excel->ActiveWorkbook;

# Replace the "*.txt" file extension by "*.xls" for Excel
$FileName =~ s/txt$/xls/;

# Turn off the "This file already exists" message.
$Excel->{DisplayAlerts} = 0;
# Save file as Excel 2000-2003 Workbook (command for Excel 2007)
$Workbook->SaveAs({Filename => $FileName, FileFormat => xlExcel8});
$Excel->Quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

try using [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm#DESCRIPTION).
it supports user defined delimiters. See module description.